# Apache Superset docker-compose up cypress failure

Tags: npm, docker-compose, cypress, apache-superset

I tried to create the docker images of Apache Superset v1.5.0 using the provided command from their homepage (https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose/)

```
TAG=1.5.0 docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml pull
TAG=1.5.0 docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

However, the images build, except the `superset-node` one. It fails after about 15-20min with the following error trace:

```
js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /app/superset-frontend/node_modules/cypress
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node index.js --exec install
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:361
npm ERR!       throw err;
npm ERR!       ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module '/app/superset-frontend/node_modules/check-more-types/dist/check-more-types.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
npm ERR!     at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
npm ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/superset-frontend/node_modules/cypress/lib/util.js:15:12)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   path: '/app/superset-frontend/node_modules/check-more-types/package.json',
npm ERR!   requestPath: 'check-more-types'
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-03T09_44_34_342Z-debug.log
```

Since I did not change anything in the configuration yet, I don't really understand where and why that problem occurs.

I'd be happy if anyone could help me sort out that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround in one of Superset's [GitHub issues](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/17949#issuecomment-1062972403).

Basically, I followed the steps as described in that (currently open) issue.

1. Remove all the node modules in superset-frontend folder.
2. Delete all volumes in docker related to the existing container. (`docker-compose down -v`)
3. `docker build -t apache/superset:1.5.0 .`
4. `TAG=1.5.0 docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`

It seems more like a workaround right now, so if anyone has a better solution or an explanation why it is not working properly, please add it.